# How to remove multiple commas but keep one in between two values in a csv file?

Tags: r, bash, shell, csv, command-line

I have a csv file with millions of records like below

```
1,,,,,,,,,,a,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,456,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3455,,,,,,,,,,
1,,,,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,467,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3445,,,,,,,,,,
2,,,,,,,,,,c,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,567,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4656,,,,,,,,,,
```

I have to remove the extra commas between two values and keep only one. The output for the sample input should look like

```
1,a,4,456,3455
1,b,5,467,3445
2,c,6,567,4656
```

How can I achieve this using shell since it automates for the other files too.
I need to load this data in to a database. Can we do it using R?

Comment: `awk -F',*' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}; {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file`

Comment: @Cyrus nice! would deserve a proper answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: This only works if number of columns is known.

Comment: @Cyrus: you could make a loop on the number of fields. But yeah `sed` forever :) although I heard that `awk` was a tad faster.

Comment: Thank You very much. I did not mention that I have lot of columns like above . Will it work in that case also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` method:

```
sed -e "s/,\+/,/g" -e "s/,$//" input_file > output_file
```

Turns multiple commas to single comma and also remove last comma on line.

Answer (score 4):

Edited to address modified question.

R solution.

The original solution provided was just processing text. Assuming that your rows are in a structure, you can handle multiple rows with:

```
# Create Data
Row1 = "1,,,,,,,a,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,456,,,,,,,,,,,3455,,,,,,,"
Row2 = "2,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,567,,,,,,,,,,,4566,,,,,,,"
Rows = c(Row1, Row2)

CleanedRows = gsub(",+", ",", Rows)           # Compress multiple commas
CleanedRows = sub(",\\s*$", "", CleanedRows)  # Remove final comma if any
[1] "1,a,4,456,3455" "2,b,5,567,4566"
```

But if you are trying to read this from a csv and compress the rows,

```
## Create sample data
Data =read.csv(text="1,,,,,,,a,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,456,,,,,,,,,,,3455,,,,,,,
2,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,567,,,,,,,,,,,4566,,,,,,,",
header=FALSE)
```

You code would probably say
`Data = read.csv("YourFile.csv", header=FALSE)`

```
Data = Data[which(!is.na(Data[1,]))]
Data
  V1 V8 V18 V27  V38
1  1  a   4 456 3455
2  2  b   5 567 4566
```

**Note**:  This assumes that the non-blank fields are in the same place in every row.

Comment: Do we need to do row by row using R?

Comment: Might be faster/simpler to use `readLines` and then your `gsub` code to clear out the extra commas, and only then parse what remains into a data frame.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tr -s`:

```
echo 'a,,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,c' | tr -s ','
```

Output:

```
a,b,c
```

If the input line has trailing commas, `tr -s ','` would squeeze those trailing commas into one comma, but to be rid that one requires adding a little `sed` code: `tr -s ',' | sed 's/,$//'`.

---

Speed.  Tests on a 10,000,000 line test file consisting of the first line in the OP example, repeated.

1. **3  seconds**.  `tr -s ','`  (but leaves trailing comma)
2. **9  seconds**.  `tr -s ',' | sed 's/,$//`
3. **30 seconds**.  `sed -e "s/,\+/,/g" -e "s/,$//"` ([Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333833/6136214).)

Comment: `echo 'a,,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,c,' | tr -s ','` leaves a comma in the end.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre,  true, it does fail to remove that last comma.   Appending a `| sed 's/,$//'` (as in your own answer) would fix that...

Comment: `tr` is usually better than others because it's simpler. In that case, you have to run `sed` anyway. But now your answer is correct at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file that's really a CSV file, it might have quoting of commas in a few different ways, which can make regex-based CSV parsing unhappy.

I generally use and recommend `csvkit` which has a nice set of CSV parsing utilities for the shell. Docs at http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Your exact issue is answered in csvkit with this set of commands. First, `csvstat` shows what the file looks like:

`$ csvstat -H --max tmp.csv | grep -v None
  1. column1: 2
 11. column11: c
 27. column27: 6
 42. column42: 567
 63. column63: 4656`

Then, now that you know that all of the data is in those columns, you can run this:

`$ csvcut -c 1,11,27,42,63  tmp.csv
1,a,4,456,3455
1,b,5,467,3445
2,c,6,567,4656`

to get your desired answer.

Comment: Thank you vielmetti

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do it using R?

Provided your input is as shown, i.e., you want to skip the same columns in all rows, you can analyze the first line and then define column classes in `read.table`:

```
text <- "1,,,,,,,,,,a,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,456,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3455,,,,,,,,,,
         1,,,,,,,,,,b,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,467,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3445,,,,,,,,,,
         2,,,,,,,,,,c,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,567,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4656,,,,,,,,,,"

tmp <- read.table(text = text, nrows = 1, sep = ",")
colClasses <- sapply(tmp, class)
colClasses[is.na(unlist(tmp))] <- "NULL"
```

Here I assume there are no actual NA values in the first line. If there could be, you'd need to adjust it slightly.

```
read.table(text = text, sep = ",", colClasses = colClasses)
#  V1 V11 V27 V42  V63
#1  1   a   4 456 3455
#2  1   b   5 467 3445
#3  2   c   6 567 4656
```

Obviously, you'd specify a `file` instead of `text`.

This solution is fairly efficient for smallish to moderately sized data. For large data, substitute the second `read.table` with `fread` from package data.table (but that applies regardless of the skipping columns problem).